# Define n spheres such that no 2 spheres will overlap each other

Tags: matlab, math, geometry, geometry-surface

I have a matlab/math question,

I want to define n spheres (each sphere should be defined by a single 3D point and a radius) such that no two spheres will overlap each other.
The spheres should be completely random (as long as they don't overlap each other).

Is there an efficient way of doing so?

I know there's an option to define each time a sphere that is farther than the current farthest sphere (you can define how far the sphere is by norm(center)+radius). but that way, we miss many possible options (like defining two spheres that are on the same distance from the origin and still don't overlap each other).

anyone has a smarter way?

Thanks

Comment: How should the spheres be distributed? E.g. uniformly within a certain boundary, normally or something else? Also, is only the location random or the radius of each sphere as well?

Comment: Both the center and the radius of each sphere should be random. it should be uniformly distributed, meaning that each point in the 3D space should have the same probability to be picked as a center of a sphere (unless the point is currently inside another sphere). but as MBo commented bellow, maybe it's impossible.

Comment: @David Consider going trhough all your questions and accepting thise that helped you. It is common practice in SO to do so, that way in the future people will know the answe is correct

Comment: Not in all my questions I eventually got the answer I expected. Indeed in this case I thought that I accepted the answer but apparently I didn't. I accepted it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to generate "completely random" data, some limitations always do exist.

You can generate random points, then build Voronoi diagram for this point set and make spheres centered in these points and with radii not larger than distance to the closest Voronoi cell face

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know it's impossible. I'll read about Voronoi diagram thanks.
So you're saying that first I pick n random 3D points (n centers) without any limitations. then I use the Voronoi diagram to calculate the n radiuses?

Comment: Any random generatation method has some parameters, so it's hard to say "without any limitations".

Comment: Let's assume that matlab's rand() function is the perfect uniform random generation. so did you mean that I should first calculate the n centers randomly (say centers=rand(n,3)) and then calculate the radiuses using voronoi?